# case expression in c++ returns error

Tags: c++, constants

I was using this code as part of a 2 dimensional game, but when i tried compiling it, it returned the following error:

```
error C2051: case expression not constant.
```

This is my code:

```
switch(_getch()){
  case "w":
    dir = UP;
    break;
  case "a":
    dir = LEFT;
    break;
  case "s":
    dir = DOWN;
    break;
  case "d":
    dir = RIGHT;
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: The way more important error: `invalid conversion from const char* to int [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use character literals (`'w'`) instead of string literals (`"w"`) in switch cases:

```
case 'w':
    dir = UP;
    break;
```

`"w"` is a string literal, which would decay to a `char const*` pointer. `switch` cases cannot be anything other than a constant integer, an enum or a class with a single non-explicit integer or enum conversion operator. A pointer to char is none of those.

Comment: How does this explain the `case expression not constant` error? You just say how to fix it.

Comment: The question lacks the actual question so I didn't think of it. I'll edit.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Edited. I hope it's better now.

Comment: I don't think the compiler is allowed to place the string literal in multiple places in the TU. But nonetheless, I think it is because `"w"` has to be stored somewhere, and that pointer can not be constant - I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'll check at the source, I'm sure there's nothing stopping the compiler from combining `"abcdef"` and `"def"` buffers, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 n4140 *Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.*. So I wasn't wrong, I think.

Comment: Good find :) Thanks